# Sending Data from Android App to Server using JSON

Tags: android, json, http-post

I am trying to insert data in a local server from android application.I am just testing my application's post method. When I send data [Testing Server](http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet) shows those data but when I test my application in [ADD_TASK](http://192.168.1.145/tracker/index.php/json/add_task) local server, it does not show data. Probably my application is not sending the data in JSON Arrary formate. I am following the same code from [here](https://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/the-simplest-way-to-post-parameters-between-android-and-php/). Codes that I have edited to access my local server are listed below.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnPost:
            if(!validate())
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter some data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
            new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet");
            break;
    }

}
```

and

```
public static String POST(String url, Person person){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("task_title", person.getName());
        jsonObject.accumulate("task_details", person.getCountry());
        jsonObject.accumulate("ma_priority_id", person.getTwitter());

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();

        // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib
        // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // 11. return result
    return result;
}
```

Here this code does not generates any error message it is showing the Toast Message **Data Sent!**.
Can anyone tell me the solution? Your prompt responses are highly appreciated.

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated, you must use HttpUrlConnection()

Comment: Use Volley to get fast and efficient result, refer this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
 public String request(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        // httpPost.setHeader("encytype", "multipart/form-data");

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Buffer Error" + "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    return json;
}
```

Comment: This is deprecated, you must use HttpUrlConnection();

Answer (score 0):

Although not a proper answer you can give this  a try, it is working code and it uses the suggested HttpUrlConnection:

```
public static String postJSON(String myurl, JSONArray jarr) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer response = null;
        try {
            JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
            parameters.put("phoneType", "Android");
            parameters.put("jsonArray", jarr);
            parameters.put("key", "testkey");
            parameters.put("mail", "xyz@gmail.com");

            URL url = new URL(myurl);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(parameters.toString());
            System.out.println("params.tostring" + parameters.toString());

            writer.close();
            out.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            System.out.println("Response in universal: " + response.toString());
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + exception);
        }

        return response.toString();
    }
```

On the php side:

```
<?php



    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    print_r($obj);
    print_r("this is a test");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this project as library:

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidHttpRestService

It's extremely easy and I use it for all my projects! It's under continous improvement...

Asap (maybe this week) I'll make an update in order to adapt it to Android Studio...

I hope it helps!!